# No sound in any linux distribution

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, audio

I've been struggling with this issue for a lot of and I tried almost everything. It happened in Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Manjaro. My internal speakers doesn't work but my headphones do. Sometimes when something starts to play on the laptop, the speakers do a quick noise so I assume they are not dead, but I can't figure what's the problem.

My laptop is ASUS UX303UB. I have Manjaro installed now.

Using kernel **4.19.66-1-MANJARO**

I've tried:

- checking alsamixer
- reloading alsa
- reinstalling pulseaudio
- use hdajackretask to override headphones
- deleting pulse config
- modify alsa.conf

  ```
  lspci -v 

  00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
  Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
  Memory at df228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
  ```

Ask for any information needed

Comment: What's the make and model of your laptop? Please get the model number from the serial number sticker, because numbers elsewhere on the laptop can be 'marketing' model number which apply to multiple different hardware configurations. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].